# npm appium install error

Tags: node.js, npm, appium

I am getting the following error while installing appium through npm. 
I have already installed gulp. still this error is not getting resolved. anybody faced similar issues.

```
  appium@1.5.3 prepublish /Users/m472395/appium
`enter code here`gulp prepublish

module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'appium-gulp-plugins'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/m472395/appium/gulpfile.js:4:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)

npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /Users/m472395/appium
npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.4.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "appium"
npm ERR! node v7.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! appium@1.5.3 prepublish: `gulp prepublish`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the appium@1.5.3 prepublish script 'gulp prepublish'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the appium package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     gulp prepublish
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs appium
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls appium
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/m472395/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: have you installed "appium-gulp-plugins" ?

Comment: Error looks pretty explicit

Comment: uninstall appium 1.5.3 first and then try

Answer (score 0):

`npm uninstall appium` and `npm install -g appium`. If you are looking for 1.5.3 itself, `npm install -g appium@1.5.3`